# Java Module Issues

Tags: java

Hey I am making a game in java using slick and run into all these errors. It works on my friend's computer but not on mine. I've tried on both mac and pc.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:135)
at Game.start(Game.java:37)
at Main.main(Main.java:5)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

What does above exception mean??

I do have it in my class path.

Comment: It likely means that you don't have LWJGL on your classpath when you go to execute this application.

Comment: It means you don't have the LWJGL library in java.library.path. Depending on the platform either the DLL or the .so needs to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains it all, you dont have a LWJGL on your classpath. You need to install it so as to get it working on your system.

Also you need to point the jvm to the location where the native files are located using a command line parameter `-Djava.library.path="path/to/natives"`. [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) is an alternative to this

You may check [this](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Setting_Up_LWJGL_with_Eclipse) for details

Answer (score 0):

The lwgjl native library cannot be found and loaded. Set the path to the folder where lwjgl.dll  (if on Windows, on Mac probably liblwjgl.so) is located, with -D, for instance

```
  java -Djava.library.path=C:\Java\ljwgl\libs com.mypackage.MyProgram
```

The library files must have a permission to be executed. Some computers may be configured to suppress any execution from USB stick so check.

If still does not work, try to call [System.load(String fullFilePath)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#load%28java.lang.String%29) from your code, pointing to the location where the file clearly exists. If this works at the end, you can use this function to load library without name alterations and path assumptions. If does not, it may be wrong achitecture (64 vs 32 bit, permission problems (not executable) or the library file is just broken.

Comment: Added some instructions for the really hopeless cases.